# Аудио плеер с использованием Serial и самплрейтом >8MHz

Tags: аудио, arduino

Есть ардуина (Nano/Uno), туда через USB передаются данные `cat FILE.wav > /dev/ttyUSB0`.
Хочу воспроизвести его. Нашёл скетчи в интернете (например, https://github.com/idanre1/audioStreamArduino), но у всех плохой звук (Не получается сделать SampleRate >8MHz).
Может-ли вообще Uno или Nano воспроизводить более-менее качественный звук без использования сторонних плат?